# GameScene to ViewController in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need do a link of Spritekit GameViewController to ViewController in Storyboard when a method said (in swift), is the end Screen (but it has a button to go to the first an repeat - this run good).

I try do in override func viewDidLoad() :

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finPartidaViewController") as! finPartidaViewController!

            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)*
```

but if I write this the IOS app crash and without it run perfect.